# How to allow only floats in a JTextField in Java

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextfield

I am trying to add a simple currency converter tool to my program yet I hit barrier. Is there a simple way of only allowing float numbers as input to a JTextField in Java. From what I have read online, using JFormattedTextField is a pain to use. Would I need to create a class to do some filtering?

Comment: don't believe everything you read online :-) It certainly has a learning curve, but doing it from scratch is even more daunting ... and wouldn't be tested as thoroughly

Answer (score 2):

JFormattedTextField shouldnt be all too dificult.  Just need to pass in a Formatter in as a parameter and should take care of itself.  you can get that from the java API which would use the region settings like so:

new JFormattedTextField(java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance());

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html).

> Formatted text fields provide a way for developers to specify the valid set of characters that can be typed in a text field. Specifically, the JFormattedTextField class adds a formatter and an object value to the features inherited from the JTextField class. The formatter translates the field's value into the text it displays, and the text into the field's value. [See examples.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JFormattedTextField`, but it gives a really terrible user experience. Better to discard inappropriate characters as the are entered. `DocumentFilter` provides a relatively (for Swing) clean way to do this. (Edit: Original answer had links to a trivial example I wrote on my now defunct blog.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with vcetinick because JFormattedTextField is useful for formatting text input.

However, if you want to verify the value inputted in JTextField, you may need to implement ActionListener yourself:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    JTextField textfield = (JTextField)evt.getSource();
    String strTextValue = textfield.getText();
    try {
        if (strTextValue.equals("")) {
           // Handle empty string
        } else {
           double dValue = Double.parseDouble(strTextValue);
           // Handle valid value
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle invalid value
    }
}
```